# How to instantiate Unity GameObjects into tiles during runtime?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a 2D Tower Defense game in Unity where the player will be able to place the walls themself. I'm having problems with making it possible to instantiate the cubes into tiles on a tilemap. I can't find any tutorials about it online. In the code below the placing part works but I don't know how to include tilemaps.

Here's the code I'm at right now:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.AI.Navigation;

public class WallSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{


    public GameObject[] wallPreFab;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
        {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            int rand = Random.Range(0, wallPreFab.Length);
            GameObject wallToSpawn = wallPreFab[rand];

            Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            Vector3 offset = new Vector3(0, 0, 10);
            Instantiate(wallToSpawn, mousePos + offset, Quaternion.identity);

        
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse1))
        {
        
        }
    }
}
```